# How can I use trigger to have the value of the difference of new and old value entered?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I am trying to build the trigger that set the variable value as the difference of the newSalary and oldSalary.

table name is trg and below is the code for triger:

```
DELIMITER //  

create trigger salary after update 
on trg
for each row
begin
DECLARE diff integer;
set @diff = new.salary - old.salary;
end;
```

but even after trying to update the value of any column the variable diff is not being set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trigger code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER salary 
    AFTER UPDATE ON trg 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        SET @diff = NEW.salary - OLD.salary; 
    END ; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Then Pick up your variable (@diff)

```
SELECT @diff;
```

Comment: dont we require declare statement in it??

Comment: No! you don't need!(user-defined variable).https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html